# match regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have  strings as below

`201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802` and `/50-Washington-St`

I am writing a regex to match both the strings.

```
((/^([0-9]+)-([^_]+)-([A-Za-z]{1,})$/ =~ data ) == 0)
```

But the above regex matches only `50-Washington-St` and not the second one.

So what could be wrong in this regex.?

The updated list of the strings that should match:

```
201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802
/50-Washington-St
49220-Sunrose-Ln_Palm-Desert_CA_92260
201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802
50-Washington-St
```

Comment: What is the rule, pattern?

Comment: what exactly do you want to match?

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko I want to match both the strings. i.e strings with hyphens and also string with underscores and digits at the end

Comment: I think you forgot abobut the underscore

Answer (score 5):

You may fix the regex like

```
/^\/?([0-9]+)-(.+?)-(\w+)$/
```

or to match the whole *string* (mind the `^` matches the *line* start and `$` line end in Ruby regex):

```
/\A\/?([0-9]+)-(.+?)-(\w+)\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/YG9e1BTjRs)

**Pattern details**:

- `\A` - string start
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(.+?)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than linebreak chars
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\w+)` - Group 3: one or more word (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) characters
- `\z` -  end of string.

Comment: Stribizew but it is not passing "/50-Washington-St" with your regex

Comment: Why should it? It does not resemble the strings in your question. But you may add `\W*` (if you want to allow any number of non-word chars at the start) or `\/?` (to only allow an optional `/`) right after `^` or `\A`.

Comment: Stribizew  ((/^([0-9]+)-([^\W*_-]+)-(\w+)$/ =~ "/50-Washington-St" ) == 0)

Comment: See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/Q2MFTw), there is a match for both the `201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802` and `/50-Washington-St`.

Comment: Just a note: if you do not care about what chars there are in Group 3, you may replace `(\w+)` with `(.*)` to just match the rest of the line (or add `/m` modifier to match the rest of the *string*).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a way of approaching problems like this one. The main take-away is that complex regular expressions can be constructed in the same way as other Ruby code: create small code modules that can be easily tested and then combine those modules.

Consider the first string that must match the regex.

```
s = "201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802"
```

As this string contains no characters that need to be escaped, we can create a regex that will exactly match this string by merely replacing the double-quotes with forward slashes and adding start-of-string (`\A`) and end-of-string (`\z`) anchors:

```
r = /\A201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802\z/
  #=> /\A201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802\z/ 
s =~ r
  #=> 0
```

This is what we have:

```
/\A201-Grandview\-Dr_Early_TX_76802\z/
   ⬆︎street number
          ⬆︎street name
                  ⬆︎street name suffix
                      ⬆︎city
                           ⬆︎state
                                ⬆︎zip
```

Presumably the regex should match a string if and only if the string contains allowable values for each of these six fields and has the formatting shown between adjacent fields.

Let's begin by stipulating a separate regex for each of the six fields. Naturally, all of these regexes may need to be modified to suit requirements.

*Street number*

Typical street numbers might be "221", "221B", "221b". Let's say we might also have "A19" or "221BZ" but not "221-B". We might then write:

```
number = /[[:alnum:]]+/
```

(Search for "POSIX" in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html).)

*Street name*

I have assumed street names consist of a single word or multiple words separated by a single space, where each word is all lowercase except for the first letter, which is capitalized.

```
street = /[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*/
```

`/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+` matches the first word, `(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]])*` matches a space followed by a capitalized word, repeated zero or more times (`(?:...)` is a non-capture group. The trailing `*` means repeat zero or more times.)

*Street name suffix*

I have assumed the street name suffix (e.g., 'Street', 'St.') is a single word, all lower case except the first character, which is upper case, optionally ending with a period:

```
suffix = /[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.?/
```

*City*

I have assumed that names of cities has the same requirements as do names of streets:

```
city = street
  #=> /[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*/
```

*State*

States are given by two capital letters:

```
state = /[[:upper:]]{2}/
```

We could be more precise by writing:

```
state = Regexp.union %w| AL AK AZ ... |
```

but then we'd have to update it every time a territory became a new state or (possibly due to recent events) a state secedes from the union.

*Zip code*

Zip codes are five digits or nine digits with a dash or hyphen after the first four digits.

```
zip = /\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?/
```

Using

```
/\A201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802\z/
```

as our pattern, our overall regex is therefore the following:

```
r1 = /
     \A # match start of string 
     #{number}
     -
     #{street}
     -
     #{suffix}
     _
     #{city}
     _
     #{state}
     _
     #{zip}
     \z # match end of string
     /x # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> /
  #   \A # match start of string 
  #   /(?-mix:[[:alnum:]]+)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.?)
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]]{2})
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)
  #   \z # match start of string 
  /x
```

Let's try it for the first string and variations thereof:

```
"201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802" =~ r1
   #=> 0
"221B-Grand View-Dr._El Paso_TX_76802-0000" =~ r1
   #=> 0
"2A0B1-Grandview-Dr_Early_ZZ_76802" =~ r1
   #=> 0
"201-GrandView-Dr_Early_TX_76802" =~ r1
   #=> nil
"201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_7680" =~ r1
   #=> nil
"201-Pi11ar-St_Early_TX_76802" =~ r1
   #=> nil
"I live at 201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802" =~ r1
   #=> nil
"201-mg Circle-Lane_Early_TX_76802" =~ r1
   #=> nil
```

Now consider the second example string for which there should be a match:

```
"/50-Washington-St"
```

We see the regex for this is simply

```
r2 = /
     \A
     \/
     #{number}
     -
     #{street}
     -
     #{suffix}
     \z
     /x
 #=> /
 #   \A
 #   \/
 #   (?-mix:[[:alnum:]]+)
 #   -
 #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
 #   -
 #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.?)
 #   \z
 #   /x
```

Let's try it.

```
 "/50-Washington-St" =~ r2
   #=> 0
 "50-Washington-St" =~ r2
   #=> nil
 "/50-Washington-St_Early" =~ r2
   #=> nil
```

So now our overall regex is simply

```
r = Regexp.union(r1,r2)
  #=> /(?x-mi:
  #   \A # match start of string 
  #   (?-mix:[[:alnum:]]+)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.?)
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]]{2})
  #   _
  #   (?-mix:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)
  #   \z # match end of string
  #   )|(?x-mi:
  #   \A
  #   \/
  #   (?-mix:[[:alnum:]]+)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(?:\s[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)*)
  #   -
  #   (?-mix:[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+\.?)
  #   \z
  #   )/ 

"201-Grandview-Dr_Early_TX_76802" =~ r
  #=> 0
"/50-Washington-St" =~ r
  #=> 0
```